# Cocos2D. How to tint a sprite back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, tint

Let's say i've applied the following tinting to my sprite:

```
CCTintTo *tint = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:50 green:50 blue:50];
[self runAction:tint];
```

How do i tint it back? How to recover previous color and make the sprite look as it looked before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
sprite.color = ccWhite;
```

Comment: u sure there are no other tint actions still running? Because this code resets tinting.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
CCTintTo *tint = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:0 red:255 green:255 blue:255];
[self runAction:tint];
```